# C++ : Throw Exception weird behavior?

Tags: c++, exception

I just noticed something, and I think it's pretty weird. It's not very important, but it draws my curiosity.

Imagine you declare a class:

```
class myException : public std::exception
{
    /*do stuff*/
} myExep;
```

I just noticed that whenever you throw that exception, you need to do it differently depending on whether you use `myException` or `myExep`:

```
try
{
    if (/*whatever*/)
         throw myException();
}
```

or :

```
try
{
    if (/*whatever*/)
         throw myExep;
}
```

I do not understand why you need `()` in one case and not the other.
I use clang++ as compiler, dunno if it has anything to do with it.
I use `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` flags.

It's not really a big deal, I just want to understand what really happens.

Comment: myException is a type, myExcept is an object.

Comment: Mmm am i that stupid? I really thought it was like a typedef when you do that with a class.

So you can intentiate an object that way? Thx for the fast answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo {
  ...
} bar;
```

is just a shorter way of writing

```
class Foo {
  ...
};
Foo bar;
```

You can also use this syntax without giving the type a name:

```
struct {
    int x, y;
} p;
// p is an object with p.x and p.y fields
```

In your example, `myException` is a type while `myExp` is a (presumably global) object.

Comment: Thx man, i dunno why i really thought it was like a typedef, it makes sens now, thanks :)